# Who is this giant in Hancock?

Tags: plot-explanation, hancock

In the tornado battle in Hancock when Hancock is fighting his "wife" there appears to be a huge (maybe mechanical) figure running through the destruction.

[image]
[image]

It appears to be almost twice the size of the people in the crowd and towers over the cars. Who or what is this figure?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a person jumping in the air or walking on something (maybe a part of a car?)

Comment: @Walt just watched that section again on Netflix, I could be wrong but I don't think so - the closest I can describe it as is Iron Monger from Iron Man 1...

Comment: @Walt oh good - I'm not going mad!

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It seems the internet was wondering about it too and the mystery has been solved (read below).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448157/faq#.2.1.15):

> When the people are running away from the tornadoes, suddenly a strange character runs from the left to the right of the screen. The character is about twice as tall as everyone else, and looks like a robot. **It's a street performer, on stilts and in costume.**

The performer has been since [tracked down](http://io9.com/5023487/hancock-giant-robot-mystery--solved). He's one of the costumed people roaming Hollywood Blvd. who pose for pictures.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to [io9.com](http://io9.com/5023487/hancock-giant-robot-mystery--solved) this is an extra who was wearing stilts.

> Comic Book Movie has tracked down the man everyone is calling "the
>   Hancock monster." It turns out he's a guy on stilts covered with
>   seaweed, who roams Hollywood Blvd. and will pose for pictures for a
>   few bucks.

However I've yet to find a more reliable source...

Comment: It actually makes sense. I forgot this was filmed on Hollywood Blvd, it's full of these people.